# Converting NSString to NSDate - wrong format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi I am trying to convert a string into NSDate format - but it returns value with wrong format and  also in GMT time.

```
 NSString *myString = @"10:30 AM";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSTimeZone *local = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:local];
 NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];



NSLog(@"myDate---%@",myDate);
```

But this returns

```
  myDate---2000-01-01 05:30:00 +0000
```

Where I am making the mistake, what to do to get the date as 10:30 AM, Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `NSLog()` to display the date as that will format it using the UTC/GMT timezone and its own format; instead use the date formatter to display it:

```
NSLog(@"myDate---%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```